# SED - Prefix all jpg files with full URL

Tags: string, search, sed, replace

I have an HTML file with local paths to images like so - /image1.jpg or /image2.png

I want to use SED to prefix a desired url to that like so - https://example.com.

Desired result is https://example.com/image1.jpg

I tried this -

```
sed "s#.*.jpg#https://example.com/*.jpg#g" index.html > index2.html
```

The result is index2.html which finds the image names but my replacement does not use those names. How to keep that match name?

Any suggestions?

Sample Input -

```
<img src="Image1.jpg" alt="boat" /><figcaption>boat</figcaption>
```

Sample Output -

```
<img src="https://example.com/image1.jpg" alt="boat" /><figcaption>boat</figcaption>
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's#="#&https://example.com#' input_file
<p><img src="https://example.com/image1.jpg" /></p>
```

Comment: I have multiple =" in my file like "h2 id="camp-cookery">" and <img src="boat.jpg" alt="boat" />. Just have to search jpg random filenames. Just now I discovered I had to add a period before the first *, so the search is ok, it's just replacing that match that isn't working now.

Comment: Tried it and get this error - "& was unexpected at this time"

Comment: HatLess You don't need to escape `"` in a string that isn't `"`-delimited, just use `s|="|`, not `s|=\"|`. I would recommend using a char that's literal instead of a regexp metachar as the delimiter though as that obfuscates your code at best, e.g. use `#` instead of `|` so then it'd be `s#="#`.

Comment: @tyee then you copy/pasted the sed script wrong or used it in a larger shell script that has some other syntax errors as the posted sed script will NOT produce that error message.

Comment: I'm on Windows so used double quotes and added src to search string like this - sed "s#src="#&https://example.com#" index.html > index2.html.  Tried updated version and get this error - 
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: Unterminated `s' command
'https:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Been reading lots. Double quotes are needed for Windows. Still got errors regarding the & character, so I escaped it but still got other errors further on. Found another post that said the best way on Windows is to use the -f option, external file, so I tried it and it works fine. Will post my full answer below.

Comment: I'm still on Win7 with no WSL, but as shown below the external script works great. Just tried your above command and still get error - sed: -e expression #1, char 8: Unterminated `s' command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed 's~\(="\)\([^"]*\.jpg"\)~\1https://example.com/\2~g'
```

*Details*:

- `\(="\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `="` string
- `\([^"]*\.jpg"\)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any zero or more chars other than `"` and then `.jpg"` substring.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/6n7m6q):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='<img src="Image1.jpg" alt="boat" /><figcaption>boat</figcaption>'
sed 's~\(="\)\([^"]*\.jpg"\)~\1https://example.com/\2~g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
<img src="https://example.com/Image1.jpg" alt="boat" /><figcaption>boat</figcaption>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked easily. Thanks for everyone's input. Trying to get it to work in a batch file on Windows was painful.

Command line -

```
sed -f sedscript.sed index.html > index2.html
```

Content of sedscript.sed

```
s#src="#&https://example.com/#g
```